# Xamarin , how to browse lokala files with WebView , (not preinstalled files)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

how to browse lokala files with WebView ?

I have a program that downloads a website to support offline mode.
I use PCLStorage for file IO and xamarin.forms for cross platform UI.
But I do not succeed to navigate to my downloaded html files with WebView.

I'm looking for a solution for Ios, Uwp and Android.

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

After you store your file you can read from it and display the content as follow:

```
var html = new HtmlWebViewSource();
html.Html = "content of your html file" 
myWebView.Source = html;
```

For more info: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview/

Comment: yes but then I can not navigate with links , which I want to do

Comment: What links? Are they inside of you html?